# Library include paths with same header name

Tags: c++, include, include-path

What is the best method to include a file that has same name in another folder from additional include directories?

Example:

```
lib1/include/foo.h
lib2/include/foo.h
```

where both lib1/include and lib2/include are added in additional include directories.

Edit:

The libs are from different SDK's and every developer installs them in his own place. Only thing that is sure is that both folders are in IDE's additional include paths

method 1:

`#include "../../lib1/include/foo.h`

method2:

Add lib1/include before lib2/include in search paths and because they are searched in order with:

`#include "foo.h"`

lib1/include/foo.h will be included

Comment: Method 2 is bad because program compilation is dependent on a setting (include directory order) not in the code itself. If someone had to reconstruct the project settings, it won't be obvious that this issue is even present, much less what the proper setting is.

Comment: @Mike I know that these are not the best methods, but are the only methods that I have in mind now. Because I don't like any of these methods, I asked here for better ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, this answer assumes that the include guards for the two headers are compatible (i.e. not the same symbols).

One thing you can do is create links in known locations to the header files of interest, giving the links themselves distinct names. For example, say your two libraries are installed at $LIB1PATH and $LIB2PATH, which could have different values in different build environments. Thus the headers you want to get are at $LIB1PATH/include/foo.h and $LIB2PATH/include/foo.h.

You could go two ways with this.  One is by creating direct links.  This could look like this in your project's directory tree:

```
$PROJDIR/
    include/
    lib_include/
        lib1_foo.h -> $LIB1PATH/include/foo.h
        lib2_foo.h -> $LIB2PATH/include/foo.h
    src/
```

This could get tricky if your code is in a repository, because you couldn't check these links in; they'd be wrong in other environments.  Also, if you have a lot of these links and few libraries, you'd have to recreate all of them whenever lib1 or lib2 move... not cool. You can get around this problem by creating links in the directory that contains the project's directory:

```
$PROJDIR/
    include/
    lib_include/
        lib1_foo.h -> ../../lib1/include/foo.h
        lib2_foo.h -> ../../lib2/include/foo.h
    src/
lib1 -> $LIB1PATH/
lib2 -> $LIB2PATH/
```

In both cases, you need to make sure `$PROJDIR/lib_include` is on your include path. Also, you only need to have `$LIB1PATH/include` and `$LIB2PATH/include` in your include path if the two `foo.h` headers pull in more headers from those directories. You could also put the links in `include` and get rid of `lib_include`, but I like keeping these things separate.

Answer (score 8):

```
#include "lib1/include/foo.h"
#include "lib2/include/foo.h"
```

Is fine as long as this is the actual relative path to those headers and **the include guards** are different. For example, if both foo.h use

```
#ifndef _foo_h_
```

then this will give you something you dont want (it will only include one, not both and which one depends on the order of execution).

Comment: thank you very much sir, and you: good point about the search-paths!

Answer (score 5):

You can just do this:

```
#include "lib1/include/foo.h"
#include "lib2/include/foo.h"
```

and make sure that the parent directories of both `lib1` and `lib2` are in your search path for includes (but **not** the actual `include` subdirectories themselves).

Note that if both headers use the same symbol as an include guard then this method will not work - you would need to undefine the conflicting symbol between the two includes:

```
#include "lib1/include/foo.h"
#undef FOO_H
#include "lib2/include/foo.h"
```

Comment: The libs are from different SDK's and every developer installs them in his own place. Only thing that is sure is that both folders are in IDE's additional include paths

Comment: @Felics: Which is why you have to avoid `#include "foo.h"`. Are you saying the names of the directories that the SDKs are installed in (`lib1` and `lib2` in this example) are not certain? If so, your only solution is to create links with different names to the two header files, and use those links to reach the headers. Even that might not work due to the include guard issue eznme mentions.

Comment: Why the anonymous down-vote ? If the down-voter has a valid criticism then please feel free to air it and I'll happily amend my answer or delete it accordingly.

Comment: @Mike please add your comment as an answer because it is a better method(in my opinion) for this problem.

Comment: The answer is wrong. What if the header guards the same(that most probably is)? The preprocessor just won't include the code from the `lib2`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: thank you for pointing this out - all the other answers have mentioned this problem, so I guess I should include the same *caveat* in mine.

Comment: It would be better if I doesn't mentioned it — now my answer have no a sense ☹

Comment: Well it's always good to have several useful answers, even if there is some overlap in the suggestions. I'll give your answer an up-vote anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder that with the 4 answers and 1709 views at the present moment nobody yet advised such an easy and straightforward solution.

You may include the files as you want, the only real problem that you're going to encounter is about the same guard headers. So, you have to create a header which will include both the conflicting header files. Let's call it `inc_foo_lib1_lib2.h`. In this file you include the first `foo.h`, then if the guard header was defined undefine it, next include the second `foo.h`.

As an example suppose that the `foo.h` have a header guard `FOO_H_INCLUDED`, then your `inc_foo_lib1_lib2.h` is looks like:

```
#include "lib1/foo.h"
#ifdef FOO_H_INCLUDED
#undef FOO_H_INCLUDED
#else
COMPILATION ERROR — the header guard was changed!
#endif //FOO_H_INCLUDED
#include "lib2/foo.h"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would include the files from a unambiguous directory which is in the `-I` list (That is to say the path to the directory which contains lib1 and lib2):

```
#include "lib1/include/foo.h"
#include "lib2/include/foo.h"
```

Therefore there will be no ambiguity because the precompiler will look at `lib1/include/foo.h` within its directory list and that don't happen from `lib1/include/` or `lib2/include/` but only from the parent directory.

As said earlier: take care with the guards, even if for a lib header, the name should include the lib name to avoid such confusions.