# What happens if two headers share the same name when compiling with CMake and c++?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, g++

Given the following directory structure:

[image]

Notice how there are two files named `System-Libraries.hpp`

The way I include either currently is:

```
#include "System-Libraries.hpp"
```

So clearly there is an ambiguity here. This project compiles and runs, so the system seems to be currently finding the correct header, but I don't expect this to be because of defined behaviour I think I am just getting lucky.

How do CMake, Make and g++ determine which of the 2 files will be used for compilation for a given cpp?

Note I am not asking how to fix it, fixing it involves either changing the header names so that they are different or including the relative path on inclusion, this is not what I am worried about. I want to know why neither CMake nor g++ complain about the two files being named the same and being included in the same final executable.

Comment: @Amadeus how is this a duplicate? my question and the linked one have nothing to do with each other. i am not asking about the difference between "" and <> when including a header. i am asking what heppens when you have two different headers with the same name

Comment: Have you read this part: _For #include "filename" the preprocessor searches first in **the same directory** as the file containing the directive_ ? That is your answer. Compiler looks at the directory where your source file is

Comment: This one might be a closer dup: [Library include paths with same header name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5168242/608639). I'm not sure CMake has a material effect on the issue. It is a issue that resides in the compiler and preprocessor; not the tool driving the compilation process.

Comment: I'm guessing that it will simply include the first occurrence of that filename that it finds. I had this problem in a project before and it appeared when I changed the order of my `include_directories` in my `CMakeList.txt`.

Comment: @Amadeus Yes I read that part. Notice how neither of the 2 library headers are on the same directory as the lowest level directory files. So that part does not apply for those files